# How do I toggle between two CSS classes on an HTML element in this simple AngularJS iteration?

Tags: angularjs

Angular newbie. I'm trying to toggle between `.green` an `.default` CSS classes in the current `.box` element on click.

[After JB Nizet's suggestion, I've corrected the following code replacing null with false and now it's working]

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- SELECTION APP -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" ng-app="Selection" ng-controller="Selection as Select">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="course in Select.data">
                    <div class="box well clearfix "
                            ng-click="Select.toggleSelect(course)"
                            ng-class="{'green' : course.selected, 'default': !course.selected}"
                            >
                        <h3 class="courseName"><b>{{course.name}}</b>: ({{course.duration}} months) ${{course.price}}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /SELECTION APP -->
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/Select.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories/DataService.js"></script>
```

**js/app.js**

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('Selection',[]);

})();
```

**js/controllers/Select.js**

```
(function()
{
    angular
    .module('Selection')
    .controller('Selection', Selection);

    Selection.$inject = ['DataService']

    function Selection(DataService)
    {
        this.data = DataService.courseData;
        this.currentClass = 'default';

        this.toggleSelect = function(course)
        {
            if (course.selected === false)
            {
                course.selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                course.selected = false;
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

**js/factories/DataService.js**

```
(function()
{
    angular.
    module('Selection')
    .factory('DataService', DataService);

    function DataService()
    {
        return data = {
            courseData: courseData
        }
    }

    var courseData =
    [
        {
            name: 'AngularJS',
            duration: 1,
            price: 250,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: 'NodeJS',
            duration: 1.5,
            price: 350,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: 'ReactJS',
            duration: 2.5,
            price: 500,
            selected: false
        }
    ]

})();
```

**Preview:**

[image: Preview]

The console reports no error in syntax and I'm unable to figure out where I went wrong. Please help me find the error or suggest me a better approach if there is  any. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you used your debugger to step through the code? Have you added simple console.log() statements to help you find out? You should be able to figure that out by yourself. Why would `course.selected === 'null'` ever be true? why not just use `course.selected = !course.selected`?

Comment: Since I'd set the selected property to null earlier, I failed to notice the error. I changed the null to false and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in the code setting that property to null. And even if there was, `null` and `'null'` are two very different things. The former is null, the second is a non-null string containing the characters n, u, l and l.

Comment: You're right, a blunder indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your ternary operator is wrong.

ng-class="course.selected ? 'green': 'default'"

This way, if course.selected is true (or just not falsy), ng-class will be green, if course.selected is false (or just falsy), it'll be default.

Comment: I wasn't trying to use a ternary operator but two different conditions:
green if course is selected, default if it isn't.
But yes, using a ternary operator seems to be a better approach, but surprisingly, it's not working with the ternary operation!

Comment: The problem was that with ng-class, the ternary operator doesn't work as an object. So, I removed the curly braces and now it works. However, I failed to edit this answer, it doesn't let me.

Comment: Edited, yeah forgot to remove the curly braces oops.